# Can Ajax allow me to get a listbox value before submit button pushed?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, jstl, el

I want to pass into a java bean a value from listbox prior to submit--in that, user selects a new listbox value and a table with dynamically update based on the value selected--in that, the value is used by a bean function that creates a new List based on the value and is what is used to populate the table.

It is a little table displayed to the right of the form items and is meant to be informational only.

It is jsp page and I do have a bean with the listbox set/get functions.

I am confused by ajax examples as they seem to require a url.  Can I put url to the same page?  It also seems to require the url to point at a page or xml file.  I just want the listbox value in the form from the present page.

I am not using php by the way (there are a lot of examples of php use out there).
I am not using jquery. 
I am using jstl/el.
I do understand jstl/el and bean stuff is server side and javascript is client side.

I am willing to adapt my page to accommodate a working idea.

Cheers,

David

Example:
I was asked for some code, so here is my feeble attempt. Imagine a function in a jsp called stuff.jsp.  It has in its function a where it grabs the listbox value and puts it in a variable called project_acronym.  It then tries to pass it with ajax as a parameter.  I then in the createTable function try to grab it into a java bean value called acronym and for this test case I simply try to show its value with an alert.

This does not work.  All I seem to play with with responseText and responseXML, which are just returning the web page source code of stuff.jsp.  I want the parameter I am passing, not the source code.

```
 function init() {
       document.add_user_roles.acronym.value = project_acronym;
        alert("project acro at client is: " + project_acronym);
         // alert happily shows the value.

        var url = "http://myserver.com/apps/myappstuff/stuff.jsp";
        var params = "acronym=" + project_acronym;
        var xmlhttp = false;
        try {


            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //for IE6, IE5
            }
            //Create a asynchronous GET request
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "?" + params, true);

            //When readyState is 4 then get the server output
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        //document.add_user_roles.getElementById("DOMTarget2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        // yuck, this shows the stuff.jsp source code
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Something is wrong !!');
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
        tableCreate();

function tableCreate() {
    <% String acronym = request.getParameter("acronym"); %>
    alert("acronym: " + "<%=acronym%>");

     ...  code to make table here
```

Comment: It would be great if you can share some code.

Comment: Good answers to this will be too long. Basically you need to further research the difference between client-side and server-side code, and why Ajax was created. And you need to start using jQuery for your Ajax calls rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

It is not what I wanted to do, but I made another page called rolestable.jsp that has the function to create the table and has access to the same bean as the first jsp page, but set to session="page".  I then have the first jsp page call a function when the listbox change event occurs that calls the new jsp page with one parameter (i.e., acronym=theselectedvalue).  The first page displays the table in an iframe.  I then put a meta refresh in the second page so that it updates every 15 seconds to show any changes that might occur to it.  I hate this because the meta refresh of course makes the page disappear and reappear in a very notable fashion.

Can ajax fit in this scenario with minimal adjustment?